# properties of Custom view class extended by view are not working

Tags: java, android, android-view, android-custom-view

**I have a custom class named as SingleTouchClass which is extended by View and I'm not able to change it's properties like background color**

```
    <com.pro.awais.pronoornotepad.SingleTouchClass
        android:id="@+id/canvas"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

 **Here is simple empty SingleTouchClass just with a consturctor**


public class SingleTouchClass extends View {
    public SingleTouchClass(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you code is correct and it will work fine because i try your code with my package name and it will display black color with background.

see my code change only package name.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.example.addbuttondynamic.SingleTouchClass
        android:id="@+id/canvas"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and this is my SingleTouchClass.java

```
package com.example.addbuttondynamic;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

public class SingleTouchClass extends View{

    public SingleTouchClass(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

im just an idiot.... the problem was in my signletouch class that i was drawing color like #ffffff in the OnDraw method that's why nothing was working for me